# How to grep the second number only in one line?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, unix

Given the contents of `test.txt` as follows:

```
Hello 10 love 20 haha 30
Hello Hello 11 love love 21 haha 31
41 Hello Hello 42 love love 43 haha 44
```

I want some kind of `grep` expression so that after saying:

```
$ cat test.txt | grep ???
```

I get this output:

```
20
21
42
```

How to implement this function?

Comment: "the second instance" means "the second number", sorry for my unclear expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to get the second number..

```
grep -oP '^\D*\d+\D*\K\d+' file
```

or

Use sed.

```
sed 's/^[^[:digit:]]*[[:digit:]]\+[^[:digit:]]*\([[:digit:]]\+\).*/\1/' file
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lX1qU3/1)

Comment: Note that `-P` doesn't work with BSD grep. Might as well just use Perl. (Uh, didn't notice the linux tag. Never mind.)

Comment: BSD sed also doesn't recognize `\1`. That's why a cross platform solution (i.e. perl) is superior...

Comment: you may use the same regex in perl, `perl -pe 's/^\D*\d+\D*(\d+).*/$1/' file`

Comment: Yeah that's what I was referring to.

Comment: @123 Oh really, wrong memory, sorry... Anyway, this still won't work, because BSD sed (or at least the BSD sed on OS X) doesn't recognize `\+`. Maybe ERE would work, but you'll never write a compatible command because GNU sed uses `-r` while BSD sed uses `-E`... (Also, why use BRE or ERE when PCRE does it ten times easier...)

Comment: @4ae1e1 It doesn't understand `\+` but you can use `\{1,\}` instead, no need to use flags. Also perl is only compatible in a lot of cases provided you use the same version, and in the case your'e installing perl you could just as easily install a newer sed/grep. Probably won't make much difference for something this simple though either way.

Comment: I think perlre is mostly compatible as long as you don't use cutting edge features like extended bracketed character classes. Maybe I'm wrong, I'm no expert. As far as I know, perl comes preinstalled on most modern *nixes, so no need to install anything. Also, escaping in BRE is way too painful (and hard to remember for people less familiar with this stuff — would you expect `\+` to break on BSD sed without trying?) — why don't use something better, when you need to jump through hoops to make less sophisticated tools work? (P.S. Should I be grateful that we're not dealing with Elisp regexp?)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative you might like to consider, using awk:

```
awk -F'[^[:digit:]]+' '{ print /^[[:digit:]]/ ? $2 : $3 }' file
```

This sets the field separator to one or more non-digit characters, which means that the field you're interested in is either the second or the third field, depending on whether the line starts with a digit or not.

For brevity you may prefer to use the range `[0-9]` instead of `[[:digit:]]`:

```
awk -F'[^0-9]+' '{ print /^[0-9]/ ? $2 : $3 }' file
```

Or you could use perl to capture the part of the line you're interested in:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if /\d\D+(\d+)/' file
```

`\d` matches digits and `\D` matches non-digits, so this captures the second set of digits found on the line. In the case where a second set of digits aren't found, nothing will be printed (this differs to the behaviour of the awk script).

Comment: Avinash's answer didn't work for me; this did. Thanks.